# Find numerical roots in poly rational elements with Sympy function set

Tags: sympy

I am not pratice in Sympy manipulation.
I need to find roots on particular poly:

> -4x**(11/2)-24x**(9/2)-16x**(7/2)+2x**(5/2)+16x**(5)+23x**(4)+5x**(3)-x**(2)

I verified that I have 2 real solution and I find one of them with Sympy function
**nsolve(mypoly,x,1)**.
Why the previous step doesn't look the other?
How can I proceed to find ALL roots?
Thank you to all for assistance
A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, `nsolve` looks in the proximity of the provided initial guess to find one root for each equations.

I would plot the expression to find suitable initial guesses:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import PlotGrid
expr = -4*x**(S(11)/2)-24*x**(S(9)/2)-16*x**(S(7)/2)+2*x**(S(5)/2)+16*x**(5)+23*x**(4)+5*x**(3)-x**(2)
p1 = plot(expr, (x, 0, 0.5), adaptive=False, n=1000, ylim=(-0.01, 0.05), show=False)
p2 = plot(expr, (x, 0, 5), adaptive=False, n=1000, ylim=(-200, 200), show=False)
PlotGrid(1, 2, p1, p2)
```

[image]

Now, we can do:

```
nsolve(expr, x, 0.2)
# out: 0.169003536680445
nsolve(expr, x, 4)
# out: 4.28968831654177
```

**EDIT:** to find all roots (even the complex one), we can:

1. compute the derivative of the expression.
2. convert both the expression and the derivative to numerical functions with sympy's `lambdify`.
3. visually inspect the expression in the complex plane to determine good initial values for the root finding algorithm. I'm going to use this plotting module, [SymPy Plotting Backend](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which exposes a very handy function, `plot_complex`, to generate domain coloring plots. In particular, I will plot alternating black and white stripes corresponding to modulus.
4. use scipy's `newton` method to compute the actual roots. EDIT: I just discovered that `nsolve` works too :)

```py
# step 1 and 2
f = lambdify(x, expr)
f_der = lambdify(x, expr.diff(x))

# step 3
from spb import plot_complex
r = (x, -1-0.8j, 4.5+0.8j)
w = r[1].real - r[2].real
h = r[1].imag - r[2].imag
# number of discretization points, watch out memory usage
n1 = 1500
n2 = int(h / w * n1)
plot_complex(expr, r, {"interpolation": "spline36"}, grid=False, coloring="e", n1=n1, n2=n2, size=(10, 5))
```

[image]

In the above picture we see circular stripes getting bigger and deforming. The center of these circular stripes represent a pole or a zero. But this is an easy case: there are no poles. So, from the above pictures we count 7 zeros. We already know 3, the two computed above and the value 0. Let's find the others:

```py
from scipy.optimize import newton

r1 = newton(f, x0=-0.9+0.1j, fprime=f_der)
r2 = newton(f, x0=-0.9-0.1j, fprime=f_der)
r3 = newton(f, x0=0.6+0.6j, fprime=f_der)
r4 = newton(f, x0=0.6-0.6j, fprime=f_der)
for r in (r1, r2, r3, r4):
    print(r, ": is it a zero?", expr.subs(x, r).evalf())
# out:
# (-0.9202719950522663+0.09010409402273806j) : is it a zero? -8.21787666002984e-15 + 2.06697764417957e-15*I
# (-0.9202719950522663-0.09010409402273806j) : is it a zero? -8.21787666002984e-15 - 2.06697764417957e-15*I
# (0.6323265751497729+0.6785871500619469j) : is it a zero? -2.2103533615688e-15 - 2.77549897301442e-15*I
# (0.6323265751497729-0.6785871500619469j) : is it a zero? -2.2103533615688e-15 + 2.77549897301442e-15*I
```

As you can see, inserting those values into the original expression get values very very close to zero. It is perfectly normal to see these kind of errors.

I just discovered that you can use also use `nsolve` instead of newton to compute complex roots. This makes step 1 and 2 unnecessary.

```
nsolve(expr, x, -0.9+0.1j)
# out: −0.920271995052266+0.0901040940227375
```

Comment: Thank you very much to answer.So if I want to know all of f(x) roots, is there a particular steps?I think that they are more than 2 and the others are complex.Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: ok, I have modified the answer to find all the roots.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your precious help. It is a good "gym" to increase my Sympy skill.